# Can't connects XenCenter with XenServer

Tags: virtualization, xen

I am trying to connect XenCenter 6.0 to Server installed with XENSERVER 6.0 but i can't connect.
It give me error when i try to connect :

> "Unable to connect to server '192.xxx.xxx.xxx'.
>   The connection was refused.
>   Check that Xenserver is configured correctly on '192.xxx.xxx.xxx'."

Also When i was using another computer for connecting xencenter, It was disconnecting automatically every time i connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine some details:

1. List item
2. the server is power-on
3. the network configuration is right.(try to use "ping" or "ssh" to check)
4. the firewall setting
5. duplicate IP address which has been used

Comment: yeah .. its about duplicate IP address.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible scenarios in this case .

Either
 1. The xenserver physical machine is powered off.
Or
 2. The network cable is not connected properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is pingable, make sure xapi and xapi-ssl are running.

ssh to the xen server and check the following:

/etc/init.d/xapi status
/etc/init.d/xapi-ssl status

If they are not running restart them
/etc/init.d/xapi start
/etc/init.d/xapi-ssl start

might require a xe-toolstack-restart